# How do I know which class this button is in for the action?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I know which class this button is in for the action?
When I touch the button then perform touchButton method, I want to know which class this button is in ?

```
{
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     button.frame = CGRectMake(200, 400, 100, 100);
     button.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

     [self.view addSubview:button];

     [button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchButton)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)touchButton{
     NSLog(@"How do I know which class this button is in for the action?");
}
```

Comment: As the target is `self` the class is the current class.

Comment: yep, that is right, but sometimes is not in the current controller, it's in the many levels of the view. So I should print which view is the button in ?

Comment: Then use the other syntax to pass the reference to the button `- (void)touchButton:(UIButton *)sender` and selector `touchButton:`.

Comment: Could you tell me how do you use other syntax?

Comment: You get the view the button is in with `[sender superview]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use for the compare -

```
- (IBAction) touchButton:(id)sender {

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;

   if([btn.class isMemberOfClass:<#(__unsafe_unretained Class)#>]){
     /// write your code here....
   }

}
```